# Functions using List and pairs

Tags: list, ocaml

The first function takes in a list of pairs `[(a1,b1); (a2,b2), ...]` and verifies that every `a` is different.

I tried to do this in two parts:

```
let rec isNotIn x = function
   |[]-> true
   |(a,_)::l -> a <> x && isNotIn a l;;
let isFunction = function
   |[] -> false
   |(a,_)::l -> isNotIn a l;;
```

I can't find a way to make it work, `isFunction` only checks if the following pair has the first element equal to its own. But I need it to check it for every first element of the list, not just the next one.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what you did is almost perfect except you forgot the recursive call :

```
let rec isFunction = function
   | []  -> true (* if the function is empty it's ok, no ? *)
   | (a, _) :: l -> isNotIn a l && isFunction l;;
```

And, actually, your first function doesn't only take a list of couples but takes an element `x` and verifies that `x` is not the first element of any couple in the list.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional suggestion, let's first sort your list of tuples by the first values. This is very easy.

```
[(3, 4); (5, 7); (1, 2); (3, 7)]
|> List.sort (fun a b -> compare (fst a) (fst b))
```

And we get:

```
[(1, 2); (3, 4); (3, 7); (5, 7)]
```

Determining if there are duplicates in the first elements becomes much easier, because they will be adjacent if they exist. We can readily pattern match on the first two elements in lists and check that applying a function to both gives equal results.

```
let rec has_dupes f = function
  | [] | [_] -> false
  | a::b::_ when f a = f b -> true
  | _::rest -> has_dupes f rest
```

Now:

```
# [(3, 4); (5, 7); (1, 2); (3, 7)]
  |> List.sort (fun a b -> compare (fst a) (fst b))
  |> has_dupes fst;;
- : bool = true
```